# Helm update configMap

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have value.yaml with nginxConf

```
>  nginxConf: |-
> 
>       events {
>           # set the max number of simultaneous connections (per worker process)
>           worker_connections 256;
>       }
> 
>       http {
> 
>           ##
>           # Virtual Host Configs
>           ##
>           #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>           #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
> 
> 
>           server {
>               # Listen for incoming connections from any interface on port 8080
>               listen *:8080;
> 
>               server_name "localhost";
>               location ~ ^/(assets|scripts|styles|views) {
>                   expires         31d;
>                   add_header      Cache-Control "public";
>               }
> 
>               location / {
> 
>                   expires -1;
```

And my configMap is

> ```
> ---
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>   name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
>   namespace: "{{ .Values.namespace }}"
>   labels:
> data:
>   nginx.conf: |-
> {{ include "render-value" ( dict "value" .Values.nginxConf "context" .) | indent 4 }}
> ```

I want to add a line under the word server when generating configMap

I tried but this is how I add the line at the end of the output

```
  nginx.conf: |-
    {{ include "render-value" ( dict "value" .Values.nginxConf "context" .) | indent 4 }}
    {{- if .Values.nginxConf | regexMatch "server" | eq true }}
    found
    {{ else }}
    notFount
    {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution

> ```
> nginx.conf: |-
> {{- $nginxConf := include "render-value" (dict "value" .Values.nginxConf "context" .) | nindent 2 -}}
> {{- $newLineToAdd := "add special line" | nindent 10 -}}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf := "" -}}
>
> {{- $lines := splitList "\n" $nginxConf -}}
> {{- $foundServer := false -}}
> {{- range $index, $line := $lines }}
> {{- if eq (trim $line) "server {" }}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf = printf "%s\n%s\n%s" $updatedNginxConf $line $newLineToAdd -}}
> {{- $foundServer = true -}}
> {{- else }}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf = printf "%s\n%s" $updatedNginxConf $line -}}
> {{- end }}
> {{- end }}
> {{- if not $foundServer }}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf = printf "%s\n%s" $updatedNginxConf "server {" -}}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf = printf "%s\n%s\n%s" $updatedNginxConf $newLineToAdd "}" -}}
> {{- end }}
> {{- $updatedNginxConf | indent 2 }}
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).